# orientation change for landscape and reverse landscape

Tags: android

I am using the View.onConfigurationChanged mechanism to detect orientation changes. Since the Configuration object only know about landscape and portrait, I use activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation() to discriminate between Surface.ROTATION_90 and Surface.ROTATION_270 (both landscape orientation but from different sides). This works fine, as long as I don't flip the phone from Surface.ROTATION_90 to Surface.ROTATION_270 not crossing the Surface.ROTATION_0. In this case, onConfigurationChanged doesn't get called (because both orientations are landscape, but one is reverse to the other).

Is there a rotation change event or override, which reports all 4 possible orientations?